# how to return array from jquery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
var suggest=$.ajax({
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: solrServer + "suggest?q=" + valore + ec + "wt=json&omitHeader=true&json.wrf=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        data = parse();
        function parse() {
            var parsedQueries = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion.length; i++) {
                console.log('i_esimo: ' + data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion[i]);
                parsedQueries[i] = data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion[i];
            }
            return parsedQueries;
        }
    }
});
console.log('suggest: ' + suggest);
```

when i print in console:

```
console.log('i_esimo: ' + data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion[i]);
```

I visualize all element of response and after i assign it at array parsedQueries, finally return parsedQueries, that should be assigned to my var suggest, but when i print in console suggest, i have:

```
suggest: [object Object]
```

and not my array of value. The question is: how do I return an array of values (string) from 'success' of jQuery.ajax() ???

Answer (score 1):

Since ajax is executed asynchronously it is not possible to return a value from ajax request.

One possible solution is to make the request synchronous using the `async: false` flag, but it is not recommended.

Another solution is to use a callback method, to handle the result of the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You should `JSON encode` your array at the server side which will transfer it back as `JSON` object and mention `dataType :'JSON'` in your ajax call for this purpose.